# Send intermittent status of request before sending actual response

Tags: python, http, client-server, uwsgi, wsgi

I have a server, which takes few minutes to process a specific request and then responds to it.

The client has to keep waiting for the response without knowing when it will complete.

Is there a way to let the client know about the processing status? (say 50% completed, 80% completed), without the client having to poll for the status.

Comment: Can I use Server Push to achieve this?

Comment: [Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762205/nodejs-expressjs-how-to-serve-delayed-response)

Comment: the answer for this would be highly dependent on your server framework.  could you describe?  both the server (uwsgi?) and library (bottle? django?)

Comment: I'm using uwsgi

Comment: +1 uwsgi.  anything on top of that?  usually people use bottle, flask, django, etc. to handle the request.

Comment: Nope, right now my service is very simple, so I'm not using any of them (I haven't used them before as well).

Comment: start a thread with stop event at the same time with your serverhandling function, let the thread send specific numbers (ever few seconds or whatever) to the client (client should know that not the answer) when the server finishes the work set the thread stop event (so the thread stops) and send the real response to the client

Comment: Great. I've added a small uwsgi server example. The output is identical as the first server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without using any of the newer techniques (websockets, webpush/http2, ...), I've previously used a simplified **Pushlet** or **Long polling** solution for HTTP 1.1 and various javascript or own client implementation. If my solution doesn't fit in your use case, you can always google those two names for further possible ways.

**Client**
sends a request, reads 17 bytes (Inital http response) and then reads 2 bytes at a time getting processing status.

**Server**
sends a valid HTTP response and during request progress sends 2 bytes of percentage completed, until last 2 bytes are "ok" and closes connection.

**UPDATED: Example uwsgi server.py**

```
 from time import sleep
 def application(env, start_response):
     start_response('200 OK', [])

     def working():
         yield b'00'
         sleep(1)
         yield b'36'
         sleep(1)
         yield b'ok'
     return working()
```

**UPDATED: Example requests client.py**

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/', stream=True)
for r in response.iter_content(chunk_size=2):
    print(r)
```

**Example server (only use for testing :)**

```
import socket
from time import sleep
HOST, PORT = '', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)

while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    client_connection.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
    client_connection.send('00')  # 0%
    sleep(2)  # Your work is done here
    client_connection.send('36')  # 36%
    sleep(2)  # Your work is done here
    client_connection.sendall('ok')  # done
    client_connection.close()
```

If the last 2 bytes aren't "ok", handle error someway else. This isn't beautiful HTTP status code compliance but more of a workaround that did work for me many years ago.

**telnet client example**

```
$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

0036okConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: That's an awesome answer. I've learnt a lot (and still learning..) from it. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. Just remember that this solution is more of av workaround because of project constrictions, require proper timeouts set through all paths etc. I think my first client using this solution was in J2ME. :)

Answer (score 3):

This answer probably won’t help in your particular case, but it might help in other cases.

The HTTP protocol supports [informational (1xx) responses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.2):

> indicates an interim
> response for communicating connection status or request progress
> prior to completing the requested action and sending a final
> response

There is even a status code precisely for your use case, [102 (Processing)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518#section-10.1):

> interim response used to
> inform the client that the server has accepted the complete request,
> but has not yet completed it

Status code 102 was removed from further editions of that standard due to lack of implementations, but it is still [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) and could be used.

So, it might look like this (HTTP/2 has an equivalent binary form):

```
HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
Progress: 50%

HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
Progress: 80%

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 05 Aug 2017 11:53:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain

All done!
```

Unfortunately, this is not widely supported. In particular, WSGI does not provide a way to send arbitrary 1xx responses. Clients support 1xx responses in the sense that they are **required to parse and tolerate them**, but they usually don’t give programmatic access to them: in this example, the `Progress` header would not be available to the client application.

However, 1xx responses may still be useful (if the server can send them) because they have the effect of **resetting the client’s socket read timeout**, which is one of the main problems with slow responses.

Comment: +1. This looks to be the ideal way of sending the processing update from server, but unfortunately I can't see a way of implementing it in WSGI

Answer (score 2):

Use *Chunked Transfer Encoding*, which is a standard technique to transmit streams of unknown length.

See: [Wikipedia - Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Here a python server implementation available as a gist on GitHub:

- https://gist.github.com/josiahcarlson/3250376

It sends content using chunked transfer encoding using standard library modules

In the client if chunked transfer encoding has been notified by the server, you'd only need to:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://server.fqdn:port/', stream=True)
for r in response.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
    print(r)
```

`chunk_size=None`, because the chunks are dynamic and will be determined by the information in the simple conventions of the chunked transfer semantics.

See: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests

When you see for example `100` in the content of response `r`, you know that the next chunk will be the actual content after processing the `100`.